# Math book for engineer from the functions to the integrals

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I can't find a real book for a student in engineering that is pragmatic enough. Basically i'm interested about calculus because actually this is my weak point; i want to stress that i'm interested about the engineering and not in a "pure math" book.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0442284896)?

Comment: [This](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Engineering-Mathematics-Erwin-Kreyszig/dp/0471154962) is also one of the standard books for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravitation by Misner, Thorne & Wheeler (http://www.amazon.com/Gravitation-Physics-Charles-W-Misner/dp/0716703440/). As a side benefit, you'll also learn enough about the physics and math of gravitation to earn a PhD. Actually, when I was in math grad school, a fellow (admittedly brilliant) student claimed this book was how he learned calculus. This would help with the intuition side.

Or grab a syllabus (or one each for each course in a precalculus & calculus series) and use web resources such as MIT open courseware (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/syllabus/) or wikipedia.

Chances are if Calculus is your weak point, you need to review the important topics in precalculus such as rules of algebra, methods/tricks of factoring, and the standard functions such as logarithm, exponential function, trigonometric functions and graphing.

Which books have you tried so far, and what have you disliked about them?